# Admob not displaying on Android Platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, admob

I'm having trouble displaying ad inside my android app in xamarin form, in iOS everything seems to work fine but on Android I'm just getting a blank view here the two screenshot :
[image]

[image]

here is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="2.0" package="it.HangoverApp.Hangover" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <application android:label="Hangover.Android" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3926326346203258~3222437594" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDhDVDVl6Z1vO9CwAL9xx2ypjMw-QhZAHw" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider614171362072741" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/facebook_app_name" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the code of the cell:

```
xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:Hangover.GUIPersonalizzata;assembly=Hangover" 
      <Frame  HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="15" IsVisible = "{Binding shouldDisplayAd}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest = "255"
                    Margin="5,3,5,1" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">

                    <cs:AdMobView Size="MediumRectangle" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>  

               </Frame>
```

Here is the AdMobView:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Hangover.GUIPersonalizzata
{
    ///Custom renderer per la pubblicità
    public class AdMobView : View
    {
        public enum Sizes { Standardbanner, LargeBanner, MediumRectangle, FullBanner, Leaderboard, SmartBannerPortrait }
        public Sizes Size { get; set; }

        public AdMobView()
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

And here the custom renderer:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Hangover.Droid.CustomRenderer;
using Hangover.GUIPersonalizzata;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]
namespace Hangover.Droid.CustomRenderer
{
    public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        Context context;

        public AdMobViewRenderer(Context _context) : base(_context)
        {
            context = _context;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                var adView = new AdView(Context);
                switch ((Element as AdMobView).Size)
                {
                    case AdMobView.Sizes.Standardbanner:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                        break;
                    case AdMobView.Sizes.LargeBanner:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.LargeBanner;
                        break;
                    case AdMobView.Sizes.MediumRectangle:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.MediumRectangle;
                        break;
                    case AdMobView.Sizes.FullBanner:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.FullBanner;
                        break;
                    case AdMobView.Sizes.Leaderboard:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Leaderboard;
                        break;
                    case AdMobView.Sizes.SmartBannerPortrait:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner;
                        break;
                    default:
                        adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                        break;
                }

                adView.AdUnitId = App.getBannerId();
                var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                adView.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
                SetNativeControl(adView);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here the ids:

```
public static String getBannerId()
        {
            if (TESTMODE)
                return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                return "ca-app-pub-3926326346203258/2224942897";
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                return "ca-app-pub-3926326346203258/8267251849";
            return "";
        }
        public static String getAppAddId()
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                return "ca-app-pub-3926326346203258~6439520076";
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                return "ca-app-pub-3926326346203258~3222437594";
            return "";
        }
```

Here is the log output from the ad:

[Ads] Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("23A6FE4B4656BDF0239595258F8C1876") to get test ads on this device.
[DynamitePackage] Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
[Ads] Use

```
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("23A6FE4B4656BDF0239595258F8C1876") to get test ads on this device.
[Ads] Not retrying to fetch app settings
[Ads] Ad failed to load : 3
[Ads] Ad failed to load : 3
```

Even if the app is in release mode, any ideas?

Comment: `Ad failed to load : 3` is `no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.` 1) Add your AddTestDevice id to see test ads on that device. 2) Use another physical device that has not been used for ads development and you should be fine....

Comment: I'll try , thanks for the reply ;)